How to use the Gazebo Sim CameraTracking service and plugin correctly to follow/track a model?
The Gazebo Sim CameraTracking class can be used as a service and a plugin.
How do I use follow or track as a service? I was unable to find an example of how to use /gui/follow or /gui/track as a command line gz-service. I was able to execute the /gui/move_to/model service as exampled here. I tried changing out /gui/move_to with /gui/follow but the service just timed out.
Alternatively, how do I set the plugin to follow a model automatically upon start? My preferred way of implementing the follow is as a plugin in the world sdf file. I tried this:
<plugin filename="CameraTracking" name="Camera Tracking">
        <gz-gui>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
        <follow_target>my_robot</follow_target>
        <follow_offset>1 1 1</follow_offset>
        <follow_pgain>0.01</follow_pgain>
      </plugin>

This sets the following config parameters correctly, so that when I right-click->follow my_model, the GUI jumps to the correct place. However, I want to know if it is possible to have the GUI jump to the follow_target upon starting the sim. The plugin should already know the follow_target from the plugin parameter, so I'm not sure why I still have to right-click->follow the model for it to start following.
Thanks in advance for any help with this!
